# How to isolate a variable in any equation

Tags: functions, algorithms, change-of-variable

The HP 50g graphing calculator has the ISOL function, that takes an equation and a variable, then proceeds to isolate the given variable on this function and return it.

I have a requirement for developing a solution that does exactly that. Does anyone know this algorithm, or can point me to the right direction on where to find this sort of solution?

As it stands I don't even know the math area that deals with that sort of problem.

This Wolfram|Alpha widget does exactly that: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=4acbedbe977480d19b7b682d4878cae2](http://Wolfram%7CAlpha)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Example:

[Isolating a variable using Wolfram|Alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIOvC.png)

Comment: probably only for some limited class of equations? Do you know which class?

Comment: Yes, only for first degree equations, like this one: 

V = (P + ((P) * I / 100) + (((P + I) * (1 + I / 100) * (R / 100)) * A / 100 - P * B / 100))